# Большая разница в производительности одинаковой функции при передаче обратных данных Java Neural Network

Tags: java, нейронные-сети, производительность

Использую библиотеку Neuroph 2.98

```
void method() {
    public Layer brainLayer1, brainLayer2;
    public Neuron[] brainProceed1, brainProceed2;
    brainLayer1 = new Layer(); brainLayer2 = new Layer();

    brainProceed1 = createNeuron(brainLayer1, brainProceedSize1);
    brainProceed2 = createNeuron(brainLayer2, brainProceedSize2);
    connectInputNeurons(brainProceed1, brainProceed2);
}

public Neuron[] createNeuron(Layer layer, int neuroSize) {
    Neuron[] neuron = new Neuron[neuroSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < neuron.length; i++) {
        neuron[i] = new Neuron();
        layer.addNeuron(neuron[i]);
    }
    return neuron;
}

public void connectInputNeurons(Neuron[] neuronsFrom, Neuron[] neuronsTo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < neuronsFrom.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < neuronsTo.length; j++) {
            neuronsTo[j].addInputConnection(neuronsFrom[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Если brainProceedSize1 равен меньшему размеру чем brainProceedSize2, то какой-то причине  он будет работать быстрее, несмотря на то, что количество связей остаётся одинаковым [В данном случае 2,000,000]

> brainProceedSize1 = 200; brainProceedSize2 = 10000; Время выполнения
> 0:15
>
> brainProceedSize1 = 10000; brainProceedSize2 = 200; Время выполнения
> 1:34

Пытался искать отличия в [коде библиотеки](https://github.com/neuroph/NeurophFramework/blob/master/neuroph/Core/src/main/java/org/neuroph/core/Neuron.java) по методу 'addInputConnection', не вижу отличий. Вставлять в вопрос много связанного кода из библиотеки думаю неправильно

В библиотеке нет публичного метода 'addOutputConnection', поэтому метод 'addInputConnection' остаётся единственным способом формирования связей между нейронами